# How to add 3d object in mixare

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I'm just begining with the mixare sdk and i'm trying to generate a 3d model in stead of a regular pointer at a certain location.

What i'm trying to do is generate a 3d image in augmented reality, based on location/accelerometer and compass. This is necessary sice my model is quite big. Too big to use an AR tag since the fov of the 3d would go beyond that of the camera.

Iv'e found this but i'm new to ios, and new to mixare. Any help is welcome!
Im using mixare because it's open source, alternatives are welcome as well!

thank you

https://github.com/ferdinandtorggler/mixare/tree/